# Is there a way to find the least recently used tables in a schema?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, metadata, information-schema

Is there a way to find the least recently used tables in a MySQL schema? Besides going into data directories? I was hoping there was a metadata or status trick-- but Update_Time in STATUS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA is always NULL.

Comment: Is your database all InnoDB, all MyISAM, or a mixture of both ?

Comment: in this schema both- not file-per-table either

Comment: It cannot be done for InnoDB tables embedded in `ibdata1`. I wrote an answer as to how you can with `innodb_file_per_table` enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following:

- Database `mydb`
- [datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is `/var/lib/mysql`

## Database with all MyISAM Tables

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        table_name,
        IFNULL(update_time,create_time) LastTimeTouched
    FROM
        information_schema.tables
    WHERE
        table_schema = 'mydb'
) A
ORDER BY LastTimeTouched LIMIT 20;
```

## Database with all or some InnoDB Tables

This is impossible to do with [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled because all the files reside in a single system tablespace (`ibdata1`).

Besides data and index pages, there are other things written in the system tablespace:

- Data Dictionary
- Double Write Buffer

  - Safety Net to Prevent Data Corruption
  - Helps Bypass OS for Caching
- Insert Buffer (Streamlines Changes to Secondary Indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- Undo Logs
- [Click Here to see a Pictorial Representation of the system tablespace `ibdata1`](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, there is no way to tell. As far as I know, the InnoDB Storage Engine does not update the UPDATE_TIME column at all.

With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, once an InnoDB table exists outside of `ibdata1`, you can only check the timestamp of the `.ibd` from the OS.

## NEEDED SCRIPT

The following is a script that can tell you the LastUpdated Time for MyISAM and InnoDB tables together in one Database (**provided you are using [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table)**)

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
FILEDAT=/tmp/GetFileTimestamps.txt
FILESQL=/tmp/GetFileTimestamps.sql
DATABASE_TO_SEARCH=${1}
cd /var/lib/mysql/${DATABASE_TO_SEARCH}
ls -l --time-style=+%s *.[iM][bY][dDI] | awk '{print $7,$6}' > ${FILEDAT}
NUM=1
SELECT_TAG="SELECT"
HEADER1=" Filename"
HEADER2=" LastUpdated"
echo "SELECT * FROM (" > ${FILESQL}
echo "SELECT TableName,MAX(LastUpdated) LastUpdated" >> ${FILESQL}
echo "FROM (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FileName,'.ibd','')" >> ${FILESQL}
echo ",'.MYD',''),'.MYI','') " >> ${FILESQL}
echo "TableName,LastUpdated FROM (" >> ${FILESQL}
for TAG in `cat ${FILEDAT}`
do
    (( NUM = 1 - NUM ))
    if [ ${NUM} -eq 0 ] ; then FILENAME=${TAG} ; fi
    if [ ${NUM} -eq 1 ]
    then
        UNIXTIME=${TAG}
        SQLSTMT="${SELECT_TAG} '${FILENAME}'${HEADER1},"
        SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM_UNIXTIME(${UNIXTIME})${HEADER2}"
        echo ${SQLSTMT} >> ${FILESQL}
        SELECT_TAG="UNION SELECT"
        HEADER1=""
        HEADER2=""
    fi
done
echo ") AAA) AA GROUP BY TableName) A ORDER BY LastUpdated" >> ${FILESQL}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --table < ${FILESQL}
```

This script is designed to check the timestamp of every table. The only parameter the table needs is the database.

- For MyISAM, it uses the more recent timestamp of one of the following:

  - `.MYD` file
  - `.MYI` file
- For InnoDB, it uses the `.ibd` timestamp

Comment: Gee, I wish the INFORMATION_SCHEMA metadata were more useful here. And many thanks for this handy script!